# key value stores for extendable objects

Tags: memcached, redis, key-value-store

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/newport-evolving-key-value-programming-model is a video about KV stores, and the whole premise is that [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) promotes a column-based style for storing the attributes of an object under separate keys rather than serialising an object and storing it under a single key.

(This question is *not* redis-specific, but more a general style and best practice for KV stores in general.)

Instead of a blob for, say, a 'person', redis encourages a column based style where the attributes in an object are stored as separate key, e.g.

```
R.set("U:123:firstname","Billy")
R.set("U:123:surname","Newport")
...
```

I am curious if this is best practice, and if people take different approaches.

- E.g. you could 'pickle' an object under a single key.  This has the ***advantage*** of being fetched or set in a single request
- Or a person could be a *list* with the first item being a field name index or such?

This got me thinking - I'd like a hierarchical key store, e.g.

```
R.set(["U:123","firstname"],"Billy")
R.set(["U:123","surname"],"Newport")
R.get(["U:123"]) returns [("firstname","Billy"),("surname","Newport")]
```

And then to add in transactions:

```
with(R.get(["U:132"]) as user):
  user.set("firstname","Paul")
  user.set("lastname","Simon")
```

From a scaling perspective, the batching of gets and sets is going to be important?

Are there key stores that do have support for this or have other applicable approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You can get similar behavior in Redis by using an extra Set to keep track of the individual members of your object.

```
SET U:123:firstname Billy
SADD U:123:members firstname
SET U:123:surname Cobin
SADD U:123:members surname

GET U:123:firstname => Billy
GET U:123:firstname => Cobin
SORT U:123:members GET U:123:* -> [Billy, Cobin]
or
SMEMBERS U:123:members -> [firstname, surname]
MGET U:123:firstname U:123:firstname
```

Not a perfect match but good enough in many situations. There's an [interesting article](http://ozmm.org/posts/sort_in_redis.html) about how [hurl](http://www.hurl.it) uses this pattern with Redis